# Software Licensing

Tags: licensing

Is there a licence out there that reserves my right to use the software commercially, however permits redistribution and modification of said software for non-commercial uses?

Basically I want to be the sole person who can distribute it for commercial purposes. However, non-commercial distribution and modification is open for everyone.

Comment: Please let's not vote to close this, people. Programmers need at least links to resources to different license models. "Ask a lawyer" is so often not an option

Comment: @Segphault you have a point. :) Correcting

Comment: Seems to be the same as [
Searching for non-commercial license for source code
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874956/searching-for-non-commercial-license-for-source-code).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licencing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to use [multi-licensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing) to distribute your software under two or more different sets of terms and conditions. There are a number of products using this approach, one of the good examples is [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

Answer (score 5):

**License Information**

Here is a useful breakdown of the different software licenses.  Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror [blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/pick-a-license-any-license/) does a great job explaining each license type.

---

**Name: None | Source: Open | Type (Clauses): None**

Without a license, the code is copyrighted by default. People can read the code, but they have no legal right to use it. To use the code, you must contact the author directly and ask permission.

**Name: [Public domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (0)**

If your code is in the public domain, anyone may use your code for any purpose whatsoever. Nothing is in the public domain by default; you have to explicitly put your work in the public domain if you want it there. Otherwise, you must be dead a long time before your work reverts to the public domain.

**Name: [GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Copyleft (12)**

The archetypal bearded, sandal-clad free software license. Your code can never be used in any proprietary program, ever! Take that, capitalism!

**Name: [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Mostly Copyleft (16)**

GPL with a cleverly-constructed pressure valve release. Your free software can be binary linked to proprietary programs under certain very specific circumstances.

**Name: [MIT/X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (2)**

Short and sweet. Includes generic legal disclaimer of liability.

**Name: [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_license) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (2)**

Short and sweet. Includes legal disclaimer of liability with explicitly named organization.

**Name: [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (9)**

Requires derivative works to provide notification of any licensed or proprietary code in a common location.

**Name: [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (7)**

Business friendly. Allows derivative works to choose their own license for their contributions.

**Name: [Mozilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Public_License) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Weak Copyleft (13)**

Allows liberal mixing with proprietary software.

**Name: [MS Permissive](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/licensingbasics/permissivelicense.mspx) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Permissive (3)**

Resembles the MIT and BSD licenses. Not formally accepted by OSI, and also offered in a "Windows-only" LPL variant.

**Name: [MS Community](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/licensingbasics/communitylicense.mspx) | Source: Open | Type (Clauses):Copyleft (3)**

Resembles the GPL license. Requires all contributed code to be returned to the community. Not formally accepted by OSI, and also offered in a "Windows-only" LCL version.

**Name: [MS Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/licensingbasics/referencelicense.mspx) | Source: Proprietary | Type (Clauses):Read Only (3)**

You can review the code, or make copies of it, but you can't use it or change it in any way. Allows a window (no pun intended) on formerly completely proprietary, secret code.

---

**Helpful Link**

If you do not have a software license template to use, take a look at what Binpress's license [generator](http://www.binpress.com/license/generator).  I am not a Binpress employee.  I came across their tool and found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you are the copyright owner, you can define the terms of use much to your liking...

You could require your customers / licensees to use your software under a license such as GNU GPL, Creative Commons NonCommercial ShareAlike or anything you deem appropriate.

Comment: Well, that's exactly his question. Are there ready-made licenses that are tailored to these requirements? I imagine the GPL won't work, because it doesn't prohibit commercial use, it just requires authors to re-publish the code under the same terms; CC is not really suitable for software as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you can license your own work as you please.  However, neither of those licenses make much sense.  GPL is not non-commercial, and and Creative Commons [strongly discourages](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FFAQ#Can_I_license_software_using_CC_licenses.3F) using their licenses for software.

Comment: Well, GPL at least requires redistribution of modified versions in the same form and can therefore deter some commercial reuse scenarios. Concerning CC, yes, you are right that it was not designed for software but other creative works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical case when license templates will not help you much.

Because you don't want to write your own license youself, or worse, copy/paste paragraphs you don't understand from the templates, **you really need to hire a lawyer** if you are serious in doing business in software.